# How to configure 2 database/schema in a application

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot, datasource, jndi

I am using Spring Boot for application dev.

I need it to access 2  databases/schema in my app (both are in MySQL database).

How do I configure this using just **annotations** or **application.properties** file?

At present I am using single database : configured as below

**context.xml** of tomcat

```
<Resource name="jdbc/user" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
               username="***" password="***" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
               url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/user"/>
```

and

**application.properties**  in application:

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name=jdbc/user

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
```

How do I configure, one more database/schema say customer into this application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you should use 2 datasource

link example

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/jpa/multiple-datasources

Answer (score 0):

You dont need use two datasources, just define two beans in your xml file. And one transaccation for schema, make a reference to bean where you have the connection and properties of data base